# Outputting high frequency signal headphones

Tags: objective-c, ios, hardware

I'm wondering if it is possible to output signals in the megahertz range from the audio jack of the iPhone. Has anyone tried this? Does iOS or hardware limit it?

Comment: What are you going to do with them even if you can get them out of the DAC? Just curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Marco's answer, the published frequency response of the [iPhone 4S](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html) is 20Hz to 20,000Hz.  Aside from DAC limitations, I would expect that Apple would have to have low pass filtering (WRT to 20kHz) in place to prohibit radio frequency emissions from the head phone socket or fear the wrath of the FCC.

So I'd say you are SOL for trying to create high frequency signals.

Comment: "The wrath of the FCC" might be a little misleading - the FCC mandates tests that *must* be passed even before the device is put up for sale. The only cause for wrath would be if there was cheating on the tests. The leakage limits are quite stringent.

Comment: @MarkRansom yeah I know .. I was being a little flippant!  Apple wouldn't even be able to get an iPhone near the FCC testing if it was radiating RF energy outside of the assigned bands.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what limitations are set by iOS, but, on the hardware side to output to an audio jack a Digital to Analog converter is involved. Usually these are separated into two categories, precision DAC (<= 1MHz) and high speed DAC (> 1MHz) as shown in this list

http://www.maxim-ic.com/products/data_converters/dacs/

Since audio is well under the 1MHz range there would be no reason to sacrifice sound quality for a DAC that can output > 1MHz, so unfortunately, you'll most likely not be able to output in the 1MHz range on the iPhone's audio jack.